# How to find range of $\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If $[.]$ denotes greatest integer function, find the range of  $$\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]$$

My friend and I tried solving this question and arrived at the answer ${0,1}$ but when we took the value of $x$ as $-0.14$ we got the range as $7$ and then while trying other numbers we started getting big numbers like $5,6$ etc.... But the answer given is ${0,1}$, so did we do something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how $[x]$ is defined for negative numbers. for $x>0$ the range is indeed $\{0,1\}$. Using the usual definition for negative numbers such that $[-0.1]=-1$ then the range for $x<0$ is $\mathbb{N_{>1}}$. Thus the entire range would be $\mathbb{N}_0$

Comment: Just plotted it in desmos and the range is clearly not ${0,1}$. Are you sure the question did not specify a condition such as $x>0$?

Comment: @Graviton so if the function was for all x>0 the range will be {0,1} but in this case they've not mentioned the conditions of x so we should also include negative numbers, right? so will that give us the range {0,∞} ?

Comment: @l1mbo I,too plotted the function on graph and the range is not {0,1} , maybe the question forgot to mention about x>0 condition. I did check the question again and they have not mentioned anything about the values of x

Comment: @malu, Indeed; Except, notation wise, $\{0,1\}$ is a set containing only $0$ and $1$ (which is correct). Likewise $\{1,\infty\}$ is the set containing only $1$ and $\infty$. What you are looking for is the subtly-different $[1, \infty)$, which is the set of all real numbers *between* $1$ and $\infty$ and including $1$.

Comment: @Graviton Thank you for pointing out my mistake but as you have said if we write the range as [1,∞) all real numbers between 1 and ∞ will be counted. But the question is for [.] function which means that it contains only integers and not other real numbers like fractions. So, wouldn't it be better to write the range as natural numbers or maybe whole numbers?

Comment: @malu, Ah yes, you're right. The notation for that would then be $\{1,2,\dots\}$ or simply $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's start with a simple proof** showing that when including negative numbers, it's possible for $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$ to be any natural number larger than or equal to 1.

Let $x=-\frac{1}{a}$ and $a>1$, then $-1<x<0$. Since $x$ is always between $-1$ and $0$ (in this specific example defining $x$ by $a$), then the greatest integer less than $x$ is always $-1$:

$$\implies[x]=-1$$

So forth, plugging this into the formula

$$\frac{[x]}{x}=\frac{-1}{-\frac{1}{a}}=a$$

Thus, $\forall a>1$ there exists an $x\in(-1,0)$,   such that $\frac{[x]}{x}=a$.

So we've shown that $\frac{[x]}{x}$ has range at least $\mathbb{R}_{>1}$, which implies  $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$, has range of at least $\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$.

But since $\frac{[x]}{x}\geq0$ $\forall x$ and as you yourself have shown that when $x>0$ then $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$ has range $\{0,1\}$ (E.g; $\bigg[\frac{[0.5]}{0.5}\bigg]=0$ and $\bigg[\frac{[1]}{1}\bigg]=1$), then the entire range is $\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\cup\{0,1\}=\mathbb{N}_0$.

---

In summary, when $x<0$, we find that $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$ can be any natural number greater than or equal to $1$, and when $x>0$ we find that $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$ can (and must) be $0$ or $1$, and since $\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$ as a whole is always greater than or equal to $0$, then the range is all natural numbers including zero.

A good question and a fun solution!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\bigg[\frac{[x]}{x}\bigg]$

1. For $x>0, x\ne \mathbb Z$, we have $$f(x)=0\tag{$\because [x]<x$}$$
2. For $x\in\mathbb Z$, we have $$f(x)=1$$
3. For $x\in(-1,0)$, we have $$[x]=-1,\frac{1}{x}\in(-1,-\infty)\implies\frac{[x]}{x}\in(1,\infty)\\ \therefore f(x) \in \mathbb N$$
4. For $x<-1, x\ne \mathbb Z$, it is evident from the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka5B8.jpg) that $$\begin{align} x-1&\lt [x]\lt x\\ 1-\frac{1}{x}&\gt \frac{[x]}{x}\gt 1\\ 2&>\frac{[x]}{x}>1\end{align}$$ $$\implies f(x)=1$$

From these four conditions, we can conclude that $f(x)\in \mathbb Z^+\cup\{0\}$.